# Input cuts off at 1 char in Safari

Tags: safari9

I have an issue with input fields in Safari 9 which is usually ships with OS x El Capitan.

Only the first character stays when you type and no more characters appear after.

Tested on other Safari versions and other browsers on El Capitan -- everything is fine.

Anyone observed this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: Have had this happen too. Close and reopen Safari until they patch this.

Comment: Good to hear that for once it's not my code's fault... :) Any technical article on this issue yet out there? It'd be nice to have to point "unhappy" users to.